# MYSQL degredation trouble when doing Parallel work using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, parallel-processing

I have a MySql server with the following config changes:

> max_allowed_packet = 16M 
>   max_connections = 2000 
>   Innodb_cache_pool_size = 90G

I have a multi-threaded .netcore2 application executing 1000+ select queries per thread every couple of seconds.
My server environment is Ubuntu 16.04 cloud with the mysql package

This starts out fine and everything works fast but after a short amount of time, most connections change to "Sleep" mode and those who don't perform 5-10 selects every couple of seconds.
As far as resources go, I am using about 70% of all my cpus and abour 30% of my RAM.

my server is on an intranet network so I cannot copy the entire contents, but I'll try and give all the relevant info possible:
128GB RAM,
20 VCPUS (i7 cpus),
Dedicated server

All DBS are using the InnoDB engine with the Barracuda type.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: as mentioned this is on an intranet network and I'm not allowed to copy any code.. I'll do my best to provide something similiar:

```
List<string> itemLst=new List<string>();
//fills the list here
ParallelOptions po=new ParallelOptions();
po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 45;
Parallel.ForEach(itemLst,po,item=>
{
//Open connection to MySql server
//do some SELECT queries
//do 1 insert and 1 delete query
//close and dispose connection
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: Which MySQL library are you using? https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/ or https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/?

Comment: Please post on pastebin.com current complete my.cnf/ini and php.ini (if used)
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
C) complete current text of error log
we can get by if you STOP here, for more detailed analysis, continue please
D) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop   OR  top for most active apps
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x       for a linux/unix for IOPS of hardware  extended status.
MySQLTuner.com  entire report.  Post your links, someone will assist.

Comment: I am using MySqlConnector package. 
"as mentioned this is on an intranet network and I'm not allowed to copy any code"

Comment: @orik The items I requested do not look like 'code' to me.  Just information useful in trying to identify what might cause your parallel work problem.